# PHPStorm Find and Replace in All Files Except One

Tags: phpstorm

Sometimes when I do a find and replace for a string in my project, I'd like it to be committed to all directories / files except one.  Is there a way to exclude a particular file in the GUI screen that appears before you commence your search?

Comment: **Custom scope** is the way to go. Otherwise -- do a global search and manually exclude found match before making actual replace.

Answer (score 1):

This link might help you.
No need to upvote or accept my answer if it works for you :)
[Exclude folder from search but not from the project list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16559203/exclude-folder-from-search-but-not-from-the-project-list)
Or this, using scopes: [How to exclude files/folders from code inspection in PHPStorm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129857/how-to-exclude-files-folders-from-code-inspection-in-phpstorm)